# Как подключить библиотеку с Github и запустить пример её кода?

Tags: java, github, maven, library, web-camera

Я только изучаю Java и прошу мне объяснить где конкретно у меня пробелы в знаниях.

Передо мной стоит задача написать программу на Java, чтобы она выводила имя веб-камеры. Для этого я нашёл следующую библиотеку: https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture.

Я перепробовал много способов как-то запустить пример кода из этой библиотеки, но у меня не получается.
Объясните, пожалуйста, поподробнее **как подключить данную библиотеку**?

Моё оборудование: Windows 10 64-bit, VS Code.

Что я сделал (пытался), чтобы оно работало:

1. Повторял шаги видео в [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BHyL_XK8YQ) (только в IDE IntelliJIDEA на
   Linux). Данный способ не сработал, т.к. компилятор выдавал, что он
   всё равно не находит какую-то библиотеку.
2. Установил Maven (я плохо понимаю как с ним обращаться), убедился,
   что он запускается.
3. Пробовал выполнить команду mvn install. Через командную строку
   выполнив javac. Error - Unknown symbol.

**То есть прошу объяснить по шагам**. Например: сначала скачать архив, потом в директории изменить pom-файл. Затем настроить Maven командой mvn...
Или подскажите чего я не понимаю.

P.S. [MVN-файл](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/LvU3Q-zU8JehFg)

JDK 16.0.1

Comment: 1 - создать проект c maven (можно через IDEA). 2 - в файл pom.xml в раздел dependencies (зависимости, т.е. библиотеки, от которых зависит ваш проект) добавить нужную библиотеку (в readme на гитхабе нужной вам библиотеки есть пример для maven). 3 - обновить конфигурацию maven (кнопка "обновить" в панели мавен справа в IDEA). Дожидаетесь пока все обновится. Дальше используйте библиотеку в своем проекте. То же самое можно делать через командную строку, но нужно подробно почитать про работу с maven.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Встал на шаге 3. После изменения POM-файла и выполнения mvn install получил ошибку: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test Вы не знаете, эта ошибка - следствие моих неправильных действий или причина вне этой области?

Comment: Не подскажите, почему меня минусуют? В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: У меня на пустом проекте по инструкции отсюда https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/ с добавленным webcam-capture в зависимости mvn install отрабатывает без ошибок. Но у меня linux. Нужно больше деталей: mvn файл, конкретные ошибки (текст ошибок вместо "компилятор выдавал, что он всё равно не находит какую-то библиотеку"). Возможно установленные версии jdk также имеют значение, это тоже желательно указать. Почему кто-то поставил минус - этого мы никогда не узнаем скорее всего.

Comment: Дополнил в тексте вопроса. Могу я просмотреть ваш POM-файл?

Comment: Проблема у вас где-то в коде приложения. Я скачал ваш pom-файл, закинул его в пустой проект, т.е. в директорию в которой есть только `src/main/java` и запустил `mvn install` - все сработало. Попробуйте удалить все файлы и по одному добавляйте. surefire-plugin - это запуск тестов в вашем приложении, наверно, какой-то тест не проходит, потому билд и валится. Попробуйте ради эксперимента с опцией, чтоб тесты не запускать `mvn install -DskipTests` или вообще не компилировать `mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

Comment: Минусуют потому, что код не нужно выкладывать на яндекс-диск, и нужно включить сообщение об ошибке достаточно полное. То что есть сейчас - абсолютно недостаточно, чтоб помочь. Мы гадаем на кофейной гуще.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kMcjvXqJ От вашего файла в общем-то отличается только версией плагина maven-surefire-plugin (у меня 2.22.1, у вас 3.0.0-M5)

Comment: Уточнения вносите в тело вопроса, пожалуйста. Комментарии штука временная ..